# Sending data device-to-device, Android or iOS agnostic with React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi-direct, multipeer-connectivity, wifip2p

My use case is I want to enable two devices, Android or iOS (between them, or among them), to discover each other and exchange a small amount of data when in close proximity. I'm building the app with React Native.

I've looked into a number of different libraries for this, using BLE and Wifi P2P/Multipeer, but everything I've found either a) explicitly doesn't work with device-to-device data transfer or b) only works with Android-Android or iOS-iOS.

Most of the discussions and libraries around this are 2 or more years old, as well, and a lot certainly must have changed.

My basic question is: what's the best way to do this? Is there something I can rely on for cross-platform AND inter-platform direct transfer?

I have been looking into [react-native-wifi-p2p](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p), but it notes that for iOS you'll need to create a custom module with multipeer. This is doable, but my concern is still that if I, say, want to do iOS-Android, the Wifi P2P and Multipeer won't be compatible.

I also have investigated [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager), but this seems to focus on discovering and interacting with peripherals: more of a one-way connection than my use case of direct transfer back and forth.

Would love any help from folks with knowledge of the current state of things and if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of an off-the-shelf library that handles this (and library recommendations are [explicitly off-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), but this is absolutely possible to do cross-platform using BLE. Adding react-native into the mix does make this a bit harder (the BLE libraries rely heavily on native code and it's generally easier to just write two simple programs than one complex x-platform one), but react-native-ble-manager looks fine for this. BLE isn't designed specifically for file transfer; you'll have to chunk the data into small calls to `write`.

Comment: See `requestMTU` to find out the largest block you can write at a time. (This can be surprisingly small. On old devices it can be as small as 20 bytes. But it will still work.)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense: would definitely need to extend that library to have devices acting in peripheral mode, but it does seem possible. I've also just come across Nearby Connection from google, which seems to be working for both platforms. Any familiarity with this? https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview

Comment: Again, probably off-topic for SO. I have glanced at Nearby Connection, but never really dug into it. It is just Google implementing what you can implement yourself. Nothing they do here is magic; it's all stuff that the OS allows. It comes down to whom you trust more in this. Having worked on these kinds of system for many years, I've come to trust myself more than Google on these things. They sometime get a bit over-clever, and then don't maintain it as the OS rules change. But if you have little experience with BLE, then it might be worth it (if they still support it).

Comment: Yeah, looking through docs for both android and iOS for BLE, seems like it's possibly easier to trust that the underlying protocols will be followed and I can build on each and get expected results. Really appreciate it! I actually didn't know about the SO library rec rules but that makes sense, thanks so much for helping anyway!